# Need to show SQL data in tree view with lazy loading

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I have a huge data in mysql database. The data in data base as follows for example.

```
    Level  Date      Name          Rank

    0      1/1/15    Rajesh         1
    1      1/1/15    Krish          2
    2      1/1/15    Ram            3
    1      1/1/15    Krish          4
    0      1/1/15    Krish          5
    1      1/1/15    Krish          6
    1      1/1/15    Krish          7      
    0
    1
    1
    2
    2
    1
    .
    .
    .
```

To copy to clipboard, switch view to plain text mode 
So, From the above table I need to build the tree view based on level column.
All zeros are parents followed by 1’s are child's of 0's above that, and 2’s are child's of 1’s above that (tree should be formed as below).

Tree:

```
0 
---------1
---------------------------2
----------1
0
-----------1
-----------1
0
-----------1
-----------1
---------------------------2
---------------------------2
------------1
```

I have huge set of records, more than 2 million , here I have to do lazy loading i.e. I should not read all the data and put in some container and then building parent and child relationship.

Lazy Loading: instead of reading and putting all the data memory, read the data which is currently viewing.

Here I have to do lazy loading, I want read the data of how many tree items I am showing on view currently.
I am not able to get how to build parent and child relationship with this requirement,

Requirement = Mysql data base (huge set of data) + Tree view + Lazy loading. (I am using Qt 4.8.5)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has described in "Fetch More example" in QtAssistant.